# What's the go-go track in "Our Man Bashir"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, music, music-identification

What is the music playing behind these go-go dancers

[image]     [image]

At around the 21-minute mark of "[Our Man Bashir](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Our_Man_Bashir_(episode))"?  Is it used anywhere else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Evidently,  this catchy tune is called *Girls in a Cage* by [Jay Chattaway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jay_Chattaway) who did a lot of music composition for Star Trek series, most notably the flute melody from ["The Inner Light"](https://youtu.be/RyYhbC0MXlY)

Comment: Self-answer because in researching to compose the question and searching for an episode clip for the question,  I stumbled upon most of the answer and some additional information of interest.